# GWT - Hibernate: How to display results from MySQL into GWT client

Tags: mysql, hibernate, gwt, rpc

I am very starter to GWT and Hibernate. I made a simple GWT RPC application that adds a user to MySQL using Hibernate. I declared a single method in service interface i.e. addUser that adds a user(i.e. firstName & LastName) to MySQL calling Hibernate method. Its is working fine. Now added a 2nd method to retrieve users from DB & display.

Here are service interfaces

**service interfaces**

```
package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import hibDomain.User;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("testService")
public interface RpctestService extends RemoteService {

public String addUser(String firstName,String lastName) throws 
llegalArgumentException;
    public  ArrayList<User> getUser();
}

-------------------------------------


   package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import hibDomain.User;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface RpctestServiceAsync {

    void addUser(String firstName, String lastName,
            AsyncCallback<String> callback);

    void getUser(AsyncCallback<ArrayList<User>> asyncCallback);

}
```

**Here is entry point class**

```
package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import hibDomain.User;
import rpctest.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Rpctest implements EntryPoint {

    final TextBox firstName = new TextBox();
    final TextBox lastName = new TextBox();
    final Button ans = new Button("Add User");
    //final Label label1 = new Label("First Name");
    //final Label label2 = new Label("Last Name");
    private FlexTable userFlexTable = new FlexTable();
    //final Label errorLabel = new Label();

    private VerticalPanel mainpanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel1 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel2 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private final RpctestServiceAsync calNumbers = GWT
            .create(RpctestService.class);

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        userFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "User ID");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "First Name");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 2, "Second Name");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 3, "Remove");

        //add input boxes to panel
        addpanel1.add(firstName);
        addpanel1.add(lastName);

        firstName.setFocus(true);

        //add input 
        mainpanel.add(userFlexTable);
        mainpanel.add(addpanel1);
        addpanel1.add(ans);

        ans.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        addStock();                 
            }
        });

        lastName.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
              public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                  if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                      addStock();
                  }
                }
              });

        RootPanel.get().add(mainpanel);
    }

private void addStock(){

        String name1 = firstName.getValue();
        // Stock code must be between 1 and 10 chars that are numbers, letters, or dots.
        /*if (!name1.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
          Window.alert("'" + name1 + "' is not a valid name.");
          firstName.selectAll();
          return;
        }*/
         firstName.setValue("");

        String name2 = lastName.getValue();
        /*if (!name2.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
              Window.alert("'" + name1 + "' is not a valid name.");
              lastName.selectAll();
              return;
            }*/
        lastName.setValue("");
        firstName.setFocus(true);

        calNumbers.addUser(name1,name2,
            new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                    Window.alert("check your inputs");
                }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Add the user to the table.
                int row = userFlexTable.getRowCount();
                userFlexTable.setText(row, 1, result);
            }
        });

           calNumbers.getUser(new AsyncCallback< ArrayList<User>>() {
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // Show the RPC error message to the user
                        Window.alert("Problem in database connection");
                    }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess( ArrayList<User> result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });

    }
}
```

**Here is service implementation**

```
package rpctest.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
//import com.hib.HibernateUtil;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import hibDomain.User;
import rpctest.client.RpctestService;

public class RpctestServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet  implements RpctestService {

        public String addUser(String name1, String name2)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {

              Transaction trns = null;
              Session session = 
 HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
              try {
               trns = session.beginTransaction();

               User user = new User();

               user.setFirstName(name1);
               user.setLastName(name2);

               session.save(user);

               session.getTransaction().commit();
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               if(trns != null){
                trns.rollback();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();
              } finally{
               session.flush();
               session.close();
              }

        return name1+name2; // to test flextable entris only 
    }

    @Override
    public  ArrayList<User> getUser()
             {

              List<User> getUser = null;

              Transaction trns = null;
              Session session = 
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
              try {
               trns = session.beginTransaction();
               getUser = session.createQuery("from User").list();

               /* for (Iterator<User> iter = users.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) 
              {
                User user = iter.next();
                User[] arrOfObjects = new User[]{user};
              } */         

               trns.commit();
              } catch (RuntimeException e) {
               if(trns != null){
                trns.rollback();
               }
               e.printStackTrace();
              } finally{
               session.flush();
               session.close();
             }
              return (ArrayList<User>) getUser;
        }
}
```

The getUser method in service implementation class is showing an error, highlighting method return type i.e. ArrayList But eclipse is giving no suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Now, on the client page, create an async call to the service you have created. This link would help you: 
http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Tutorials~RPC_To_Java

**EDIT:**

My apologies.

1. I assume you have serialized the "user" class. If not, you have to serialize it:

   class user implements java.io.serializable;
2. If you want the resultset to convert to the array, do a check if list is null and if result list is not null, convert it to array and assign to user[] like:

   try{

   ....

   .... .list();

   if(!users.isEmpty(){

   getUser = users.toArray();

   }

   }

   and then you can return getUser to the client side.

Comment: Ashok, kindly first see this method. I hope you understand what I want to do here but this is incomplete implementation. 1st I need to assign List of User type to an array of User type, & then I could return it. I am having difficulties in that. Plz 1st see that. I hope I can handle things on client page to make async call to this method.

Comment: Hi Enterprize, please check the edited answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thank you very much Ashok. I am doing almost same as you mentioned. But still there is some problem. I edited the service implementation part, can you plz see it.

Comment: Hi Enterprize, I doubt if arrays are serializable? could you try with an ArrayList? i.e. return ArrayList<User> instead of user[]. This would work 100% because, I have been implementing using ArrayList. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Hi Ashok, I put all GWT code in OP. You can see it, I change return type of method to ArrayList too but it is showing same error. i.e. highlighting return type of getUser method i.e. ArrayList now. If you see implementation class, may be you find reason for error. Bec I am not sure of implementation there as I have earlier used only one service method.

Comment: thank you very much Ashok for your help. That error I was talking is gone somehow but my app is raising some other errors about new getUser method. I think I post new question for that as this question is solved I believe. Thank you again :)